# Solution to differential equation with even and Lipschitzian function is odd.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let g:$\mathbb{R}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be even and lipschitz continuous on every closed interval. Show that every solution to y'=g(y), y(0)=0 is odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y(x)$ be a solution of $y' = g(y)$ with initial condition $y(0) = 0$.
Consider the function $u(x)$ such that $y(x) = - u(-x)$.
Then, using the chain rule
$$
\frac{d y}{d x} = - \frac{d u}{d (-x)} \frac{d (-x)}{dx} = \frac{d u}{d(-x)} \equiv \frac{d u}{dz},
$$
where $z = -x$.  On the other hand,
$$
\frac{d u}{dz} = \frac{d y}{d x} = g(y(x)) = g(-u(-x)) = g(-u(z)) = g(u(z)).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{d u}{dz} = g(u),
$$
and it is not hard to see that $u(0) = y(0) = 0$. Hence, $u$ is also a solution of the Cauchy problem.  However, since $g$ is Lipschitz, there must be only one solution of the Cauchy problem. Thus, $u(x) \equiv y(x) = -u(-x)$, which implies that $u$ (and consequently $y$) is odd.